# How do I create a 'Parallelogram' shape in css with a straight side?

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

I am trying to create a Parallelogram with a straight right side in css but so far I am struggling to achieve this.

I am using css ...

```
-webkit-transform: skew(-18deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-18deg);
-o-transform: skew(-18deg);
```

...to 'skew' the rectangle to create the Parallelogram.

I am wondering if the right side can be made straight?

Would it require :before and :after in the css?

Any help of this would be great.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: Hi Harry, yes i mean one side being straight.
Do you know what extra element I could add to this?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/un2yz04n/) what you need?

Comment: Nearly Harry,  i have attached an image of how i would like it to look.
http://postimg.org/image/61grr0dnd/
Cheers, Phil

Comment: Thanks harry it has been answered below.
The trapezoid was the answer with 
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 130px solid black;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

Comment: Yep, I liked that approach too because it didn't add any extra element. One thing just for your attention. With both the current approaches posted below you would not be able to add an extra border to the shape. If you need that, we have to use a different approach.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to literally flip that created image upside down too.?
So that the top is longer than the bottom?
Cheers

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. Please refer to the two versions I have updated into my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a triangle shaped element and positioning it next to the rectangular element.

**Option 1:** (Using the border hack)

In the example below, I have added a blue color for the triangular shape only to illustrate how the shape is achieved. Please replace the color in the below line to achieve the parallelogram with a slanted edge on one side and a straight edge on the other.

Change the below

```
border-color: transparent blue blue transparent;
```

to

```
border-color: transparent red red transparent;
```

**Note:** When using this method, it is difficult to add an extra outer border to the shape.

**Snippet:**

```css
.trapezoid{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: white;
}
.trapezoid:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -50px;
    top: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue transparent blue transparent;
    border-width: 100px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid">Some dummy text</div>
```

---

**Option 2:** (Using `skew`)

```css
.trapezoid{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: beige;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.trapezoid:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: -25px;
    top: -1px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    background: beige;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid">Some dummy text.</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this id to any div youll see the expected result

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLe](http://jsfiddle.net/46be3tL4/1/)

Comment: @web-tiki edited for the desired result

Comment: The edited version is pretty neat :)