# CSS trapezoid shape with text

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I don't know if this is possible with CSS but it's worth asking.

I want to have a trapezoid shape be transparent in the middle (hollow) with formatted text inside of it (and a small image as well). It also has to be responsive. Here is a mockup of what I mean:

[image: http://puu.sh/bKQJR.jpg]

Is this posible with CSS? I know how to make a trapezoid shape but I haven't figured out how to get text inside it and have it be hollow (only the outline of the shape).

Comment: [Shapes of css](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to get the shape. I'm looking to get text inside a hollow shape.

Comment: Have a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748387/how-to-bevel-the-corner-of-a-block-div/16748949#16748949

Comment: @Flopet17 at least read the question before post a comment ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993033/how-do-i-create-a-parallelogram-shape-in-css-with-a-straight-side/25993168#25993168 see my answer there

Comment: @Flopet17 just "I know how to make a trapezoid shape "

Comment: @Flopet17 I'm not 'waiting' to get anything. I haven't been able to find a way to create what I'm after, so I tried here. Thanks for your effort, but I already know how to make a shape.

Comment: @mango Yep! You can now with CSS3. [Check this article out](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/)! And also [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/). Finally, you might be interested in [this](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/10/23/css-shapes-visual-storytelling/) as well.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH. Didn't come across that one yet! Very useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `width`/`height` of the trapezoid shape should be changed dynamically, you could achieve the effect by using [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)s as follows:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;        /* optional - feel free to remove it */
  /* height: 150px; */ /* optional - feel free to remove it */
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid teal;
  
  top: -4%; bottom: -11%; left: -3%; right: -3%;
  z-index: -1;

  -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
  transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus sed unde voluptate non temporibus quae amet possimus dolorum quisquam atque nemo reprehenderit quasi suscipit vero cum delectus quibusdam optio asperiores.
</div>
```

However this method is not supported in IE9 and older.

Comment: I assumed (I could be wrong) that she wants the text to follow the shape outline as well.

Comment: @TylerH I don't see the effect you mentioned in her provided image.

Comment: @Danko That's nice, I hadn't the time to [complete](http://jsbin.com/kixida/3/edit) the answer.