# How to achieve a trapezoid in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve the following container in CSS3. I tried with `transform: skewY` but i don't have the desired result. I know that I can achieve it with 3d Transforms, but I have in mind our lovely Internet Explorer. Also I tried to play with pseudo elements but I lost it. Is there any css rule that I can, lets say, increase the height of the top and bottom right corners?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5zdnbg5/)

Thank you

[image: trapezoid]

Comment: Would using SVG work for your requirements?

Comment: *i don't have the desired result* : why? could you show us your attempt in a fiddle?

Comment: Would skewing or transforming work for you [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it has been discussed several times on SO. As a proof,  a relevant answer (of mine) can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000995/css-trapezoid-shape-with-text/26001338#26001338).

Comment: I've updated my question with a JS fiddle. I'm trying to achieve thishttp://i.imgur.com/C2pvaMx.jpg?1 and not just a skew

Comment: @HashemQolami As i said i'm having IE in mind.

Comment: @hambos22 Then you could achieve that by [CSS triangles](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles) - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/) - [Visual explanation](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh).

Comment: IE? IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10 and/or IE11?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dcru7w6a/1/ ?

Comment: @FelipeAls the three latest. I just tested the perspective option on IE and it works. (I thought that 3d transforms don't play well with IE) My only concern now is that it doesn't take 100% width. https://jsfiddle.net/f5zdnbg5/

Comment: @Jaxo thanks for your effort but clip-path officially not supported by any IE.

Comment: OP Yeah I tried the triangle method with :before and :after but it failed at the need of a (border-)width in percentage too. And I don't think the `left:0;right:0` trick will do anything better here so transform seems the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use skewed pseudo elements for this (ensuring the skews are on the pseudos, and not the element itself):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 10vw;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(5deg);
  transform: skewY(5deg);
  background: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -20%;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
html {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
}
```

```html
<div>Content!!</div>
```

Comment: Yeah at the end I did this. Thanks for your response btw

Comment: @hambos22: I'm glad I could help. However, I'm not 100% happy with my solution here tbh, as I think it might get distorted on stupidly large screens (I can't test, however). But If you were using a set size (px, etc) then this would be perfect.

Comment: I tested it on large resolutions and I added queries. I set the width for those over 100% (103%) and adjusted the angle. Also added to the wrapper an `overflow-x:hidden` and everything is ok