# Skew div border of one side only using one div only

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-transforms

I have created a skewed div using following css

```
#outer-left{
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:skew(-30deg,0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: skew(-30deg,0deg);
background:#333333;
width:200px;
z-index:20;
border-bottom:3px solid #2E8DEF;
padding:10px 30px 10px 75px;
font-size:20px;
color:#2E8DEF;
position:relative;
left:-50px;
}
#outer-left:after{
content:"";
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
width:20px;
height:100%;
background:#2E8DEF;
float:right;
right:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:10;
}

#inner-left{
-ms-transform: skew(30deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(30deg,0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: skew(30deg,0deg);
display:inline-block;
}
```

And used two divs i.e. outer div to skew border and div and inner div to cancel the skew effect for text.

[image]

But I have achieved same effect using only one div in div3

> Look at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5a7rhh0L/

IF I do the same as in div 3 with more text it gets distorted.
But not so in case of div2 with more text using 2 divs.

I am completely aware of what is happening here. I want to know if DIV2 can be achieved using only one div i.e. `<div id="inner-div">Context<br>Hello</div>` and now without using two divs i.e. inner and outer one.

Comment: That fiddle doesn't seem to work mate. Also, the question seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993033/how-do-i-create-a-parallelogram-shape-in-css-with-a-straight-side

Comment: @Harry, in that link the extra border is triangular and in my question the extra border is parallelogram. But although that gave me a hint how to do that.

Comment: Yup mate, you just have to adjust the position of the pseudo element (the second one which uses `skew`).

Comment: Could you tell us WHY you want to use only one div? I mean sure the HTML might look nicer but it would probably require some hackish CSS.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn as you said, the HTML will look nicer. The catch here is that i have to use such elements all over the page at least 30 to 40 times. And in css it has to be defined one time only. So, I wanted a cleaner html, so that management and modification would be easy. The second way I thought is to use JS to dynamically add extra html. But still if it can be done by one div only, that would be nicer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

**http://jsfiddle.net/5a7rhh0L/3/**

CSS:

```
#a {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;

    color: #2E8DEF;
    background: #333333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2E8DEF;
}
#a:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;

    background: #333333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2E8DEF;
    border-right: 20px solid #2E8DEF;

    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
```