# Skew a button one side whitout changing the HTML

Tags: html, css, skew

how can I skew a button on one side but without changing the HTML
I want to use the code like a Bootstrap button

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="">BUTTON</a>
```

It should look like this picture:

[Button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL8Bg.png)

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075318/skew-div-border-of-one-side-only-using-one-div-only this might help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761202/css3-transform-skew-one-side

Comment: https://codepen.io/o/pen/wosfH

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding to your button an `::after` pseudo-element consisting only of an absolutely positioned CSS Triangle (slightly rotated):

```css
button {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 60px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-size: 32px;
line-height: 48px;
text-align: left;
background-color: rgb(51,204,51);
border: none;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
width: 140px;
}

button:nth-of-type(1)::after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -60px;
right: -60px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 60px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: rgb(255,255,255);
transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

button:nth-of-type(2)::after {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: -30px;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
background-color: inherit;
transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Button</button>
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there also an other solution because if I have got more buttons on other backgrounds I have to style each triangle with the background color...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "another solution". Please can you explain further? Thank you.

Comment: Without a triangle... Is there a solution with transform: skew() ??

Comment: Yes, there's another pretty similar approach using another `::after` pseudo-element. See the post above for a second approach using `transform: skewX()` and `background-color: inherit`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not that [wide browser support for `clip-path`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) , but easy and pretty:

```css
.btn {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 10px) 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 10px) 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.btn-default {
  background-color: green;
}
.btn-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.btn-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-default" href="">BUTTON</a>
<br><br>
<a class="btn btn-blue" href="">BUTTON</a>
<br><br>
<a class="btn btn-red" href="">BUTTON</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo element `:after` and it has [greater support](http://caniuse.com/#search=after) than CSS clip path.

Your HTML would look like this, where you simply add a class `btn-clipped` to buttons you wish to have the clipped style:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-clipped">
  Clipped button
</button>
```

You would add styles for `.btn-clipped`:

```
.btn-clipped {
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 25px; /* adjust this to your liking */
  width: 200px; /* you can also set a width if you like (optional) */
}

.btn-clipped:after {
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 120%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transform: rotate(10deg); /* adjust this to tweak the angle */
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the clipped styles to `.btn` or `.btn-default` if you know for sure the style should be applied globally.

You can see a Codepen of it working here: http://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/dOdOOw